# Merging data with or / nvl in where clause, what benefit?

Tags: oracle

In what cases using or / nvl combo in merge update is useful and what purpose does it serve ? (If it is good at all). Typical structure bellow.

```
   MERGE INTO data_table p
    USING (SELECT pk,
                  col1,
                  col2,
                  col3
             FROM incoming_data_table) pp
    ON (p.pk = pp.pk)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN

      UPDATE
         SET p.col1 = pp.col1,
             p.col2 = pp.col2,
             p.col3 = pp.col3

       WHERE nvl(p.col1, '0') != nvl(pp.col1, '0') -- Line in question
          OR nvl(p.col2, '0') != nvl(pp.col2, '0') -- Line in question
          OR nvl(p.col3, '0') != nvl(pp.col3, '0') -- Line in question


    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT
        (p.pk,
         p.col1,
         p.col2,
         p.col3)
      VALUES
        (pp.pk,
         pp.col1,
         pp.col2,
         pp.col3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the OR's make sure that the update is done as soon as one of the three conditions is met. With AND's all three would have to be met before the update taking place. So as soon as at least one of the col's differ the update shall take place.
- then NVL make sure that null is interpreted as any other value. Because without the NVL, neither `1=null` is true nor is `1!=null` true. They both return false. But as the writer of the query wants an update to take place e.g. when `p.col1` contains `123` and `p.col2` contains `null`, the NVL is needed. Here are some cases for you:

  ```
  select 'true' from dual where 1!=null;        -- false
  select 'true' from dual where 1=null;         -- false
  select 'true' from dual where 1=nvl(null,0);  -- false
  select 'true' from dual where 1!=nvl(null,0); -- true
  ```

NULL is very special when it comes to comparisons. Not even this is true:

```
 select 'true' from dual where null=null; -- false
```

Have a look at table 'Nulls in Conditions' on this page for more examples: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm

Comment: So the main usage of this is performance ? I know a little about null's, OR usage was the big headache. As more and more i get to know oracle and SQL in general i begin to understand how important order and placement is.

Comment: @Peter - same username ^^ the reason for the ORs is not performance, no. OR means either the one or the other needs to be true for the update to take place. Here is a nice read on how OR works: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/or.php

Comment: But does oracle check further if first condition is met ?

Comment: @Peter Oracle does for sure not process them in the order you wrote them, but based on an algorithm what makes sense cost-wise to do first. But I am not knowledge enough to give you all details and I guess a full explanation could fill a book ^^.

Comment: Just one thing `1=null` is not `false` but `null` instead. So `NOT 1=null` is also `NULL` and therefore `select 'true' from dual where not 1=null` will also lead to no entries...

Comment: Thank you @Radagast81. You are right, I should not have mixed `unknown` and `false`.